# Load AJAX content in modal and change URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

My current setup is on click a modal popups with data from the ajax action which has been passed an id, I want the URL to change on click.

But I also want it so that if you directly accessed the URL it would load say index with the modal preloaded.

Very much like https://www.myunidays.com/perks/view/shoeaholics/online it loads the URL with the content in a model then if you click/close the modal the URL changes to the index page.

I have seen related questions about changing URL on click but couldn't find anything to do with accessing URL directly (is their a rule I can add to my .htaccess).

(Any code/direction is appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial view (so that layout isnt rendered twice) and add the action to controller

```
public function actionViewmodal($id)
{
    return $this->renderPartial('_view', array('model' => $this->findModel($id)));
}
```

Then within my index I did the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').click(function() {

    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    var Id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'modal_id' : Id,
        },
        url : 'http://localhost:8888/directory/viewmodal?id='+Id,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response) {
                $('.modal_some_wrapper').html(response);
                $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
                $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
    });

       //to change the browser URL to the given link location
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
        //stop refreshing to the page given in
        return false;

});

});
```

Could someone example how myunidays website works with modal and URL change?